# UICC with OTA vs mobile app using web-services with https

Tags: https, nfc, smartcard, ota

The question would be much clearer when use a concrete e.g,

Lets say I need to topup my mobile , I have two options

1. top up using sim services [UICC with OTA]
2. top up using  a mobile-top-up-app (a hypothetical mobile app) [web-services https ]

my question is, what is the main advantage of option 1 over 2? what is so important about OTA?

Answer (score 1):

OTA works out of the box as a 2G service (as such it benefits a huge coverage). It is supported by all devices regardless of brand, OS, country. The system also covers retrys to some extent. It will incur minimal cost to your customer, especially in roaming situations.

Using a data pipe works too, but you need to have an app deployed and running in the end-user's device.